# SQL Server trimming float data type

Tags: sql-server

I have a float datatype and it gets assigned to 10 decimal points. When I try to convert this datatype to varchar, it retains 5 decimal points and trims the rest of the decimal values.

```
@final varchar(8000)
select @final=convert(varchar(8000),@final)
```

Comment: Where is the float? Where is the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem.

```
SELECT @final = CONVERT(VARCHAR(80), cast(@lon as decimal(30,15)))
```

@final string
@lon float

Answer (score 1):

use sql [round](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_round.asp) method